# Why does android logcat not show the stack trace for a runtime exception?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, logcat, runtimeexception

An android application that I am currently developing was crashing (fixed that), due to what should have raised an IndexOutOfBoundsException. I was accessing a string in the doInBackground method of a class that extends AyncTask, from the variable arguments parameter (ie String...). I was accidentally accessing index 1 (not 0) of a one element variable argument string (mildly embarrassing...). When the application first crashed I looked at my logcat, (and many times again to confirm that I wasn't insane) and there was no stack trace for a RuntimeException to be found. I crash my phone quite often and there is always a nice little stack trace for me to look at and fix with, but I was puzzled by this. Here is the pertinent section of my logcat (which contains no stack trace for a runtimeexception), following a debug statement right before the line of code that was causing the crash:

```
W/dalvikvm(25643): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c281f8)
D/dalvikvm(25643): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1249K, 25% free 12433K/16455K, paused 2ms+6ms
W/dalvikvm(25643): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c281f8)
I/Process (25643): Sending signal. PID: 25643 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager( 5905): Process com.trade.nav.ges (pid 25643) has died.
W/ActivityManager( 5905): Force removing r: app died, no saved state
I/WindowManager( 5905): WIN DEATH: win
I/WindowManager( 5905): WIN DEATH: win
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1746): id=3848 Removed idx=2 Map Size=4
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1746): id=3848 Removed idx=-2 Map Size=4
I/WindowManager( 5905): WIN DEATH: win
I/power   ( 5905): *** acquire_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1  freq : 1000000 
D/PowerManagerService( 5905): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency :  1000000  uid : 1000  pid : 5905  tag : ActivityManager
W/ActivityManager( 5905): mDVFSLock.acquire()
```

And after that, another activity starts.
For reference, here is the code that caused the crash:

```
private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
    String url = "";
    //...
    public LoadImage(ImageView iv, Context c) {
        //...
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // urls has one element
        url = urls[1];
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Any insight into what is happening would please me greatly, as I am curious about having never seen anything like this on the internet.
Thanks.

Edit: I have no filter set

Comment: Did you try by putting the exception code in Try Catch Block ?

Comment: You sure that you don't have any filter selected?

Comment: ...the problem is not that I need to prevent the code from raising the runtime exception, I already did that in another version of the code (changed the number 1 to a 0). The problem is that the old version of the code never caused a runtime exception stack trace to show up in my logcat. I want to know why that would happen.

Comment: And I have no filter selected at all. I use command line tools for development though I am familiar with using eclipse. I simply use the command "adb logcat" and receive all logcat results unfiltered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your threads are clearly crashing (note the `thread exiting with uncaught exception` on two different threads in the same process).  The process is cleaning up after itself -- `Sending signal` indicates the process is sending a fatal signal to itself.  So the question is why you aren't seeing a stack dump between these two.

The stack dump comes from [RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr1-release/core/java/com/android/internal/os/RuntimeInit.java), which is the framework-provided global uncaught exception handler.  The process self-annihilation happens in the `finally` block.  It's hard to see a way to get out of this without logging "FATAL EXCEPTION", unless something in `Slog.e` fails and throws.

I would guess that either something is failing in `Slog.e`, or somebody has replaced the framework's uncaught exception handler.  The latter could happen if you've incorporated some external library into your app, such as a crash log catcher or an ad network, and the new handler doesn't log the exception but does kill the process.

You can track it down by attaching a Java-language debugger (e.g. Eclipse).  By default it will stop on uncaught exceptions.  From there you can trace it around, set breakpoints and single-step through the uncaught exception handler (if you have full sources), and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much. I plan on looking into it more at home, as I cannot find the time at work to. I do not have any third party libraries that should be affecting that (though I will check if Aviary, an image editor which I use as a library, does anything of the sort), and I am still seeing other stack dumps in my logcat (as it should be), so I continue to be intrigued. Thanks much for the timely and well-informed suggestions. Have a nice day.

Comment: It's a pity the default implementation kills the process without mentioning anything about the exception being thrown. Anything to give the programmer a clue of what's going on.

Answer (score 6):

As per fadden's suspect that external library could override uncaught exception handler, I started to investigate any possible libs. Turned out that  `GoogleAnalytics` throttles crashes and prevents the stack trace from being displayed in logcat if you turn on `enableExceptionReporting`. I remove this line of code then everything gets back on track!! That could be the first time I was so happy to see crashes!!